# How to update state from a react mapping component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I have an api which i want to filter the data and place the filterd into a state

```
export default class ModifyPage_Single extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {data:[],idd:""}
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        fetch("removed api")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) =>{
          this.setState({data:data})
        })
    }

    render() {

        const test = this.state.data.map((e) =>  {   if(e.ID === this.props.location.productdetailProps.productdetail)  {this.setState({idd:e.PP})}     })
```

But i keep getting this error Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

How can i solve so that the fitered out api goes into the state?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should NEVER update state in render block. `render` runs on every render and since you are updating state in render block, it constantly runs the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update in componentMount, not in render():

```js
export default class ModifyPage_Single extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [], idd: "" };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("removed api")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data });
        data.forEach((e) => {
          if (e.ID === this.props.location.productdetailProps.productdetail) {
            this.setState({ idd: e.PP });
          }
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the state in lifecycle methods, updating it in render is anti pattern

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch("removed api")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) =>{
          this.setState({data:data})
          const iddObj = data.find((el) => el.ID === this.props.location.productdetailProps.productdetail)
          if(iddObj ){
 this.setState({idd:iddObj.PP})
}        
        })
    }
```